# Not able to set up key maps involving <Tab> in Vim in a terminal

Tags: vim, remapping

I'm a Vim noob who liked the instructions in [this wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switching_between_files) to set up key mapping for quickly cycling through several files. The only problem: I can't get it to work!

My `~/.vimrc` contains these lines (please note that the wiki page doesn't put colon before `nnoremap`; I've tried with and without it):

```
"Cycle through tabs
:nnoremap <C-Tab> :tabn<CR>
:nnoremap <C-S-Tab> :tabp<CR>
```

And when I open multiple tabs in `vim`, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> gets me nothing. However, if I do `:tabp` and `:tabn`, I'm able to cycle through tabs.

I'm using `Vim 7.4` on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You can use `gt` and `gT` to cycle across tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!

This is not a bug. This behaviour is caused by the fact that terminals cannot tell the difference between <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

These shortcuts should work fine in any Vim with a GUI like gVim.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646819/how-can-i-map-ctrl-tab-to-something-in-vim